# CreateFileMapping, MapViewOfFile, how to avoid holding up the system memory

Tags: windows, performance, file-io, memory-management

I'm developing an application targeted for desktop systems which may have as little as 256MB RAM (Windows 2000 and up). In my application I have this large file (>256MB) which contains fixed records of about 160 bytes/each. This application has a rather lengthy process in which, over time, it will be randomly accessing about 90% of the file (for reading and writing). Any given record write will not be more than 1,000 record accesses away from the read of that particular record (I can tune this value).

I have two obvious options for this process: regular I/O (FileRead, FileWrite) and memory mapping (CreateFileMapping, MapViewOfFile). The latter should be much more efficient in systems with enough memory, but in systems with low memory it will swap out most of other applications' memory, which in my application is a no-no. Is there a way to keep the process from eating up all memory (e.g., like forcing the flushing of memory pages I'm no longer accessing)? If this is not possible, then I must resort back to regular I/O; I would have liked to use overlapped I/O for the writing part (since access is so random), but documentation says [writes of less than 64K are always served synchronously](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7e3td2c.aspx).

Any ideas for improving I/O are welcomed.

Comment: Perhaps VirtualFree(MEM_DECOMMIT) can be of help? I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: No, VirtualFree(MEM_DECOMMIT) fails for MMFs; I just checked.

Comment: Does the file offset parameter we feed into `CreateFileMapping` translates to the amount of RAM consumed by the `map object`? I don't understand well why this offset becomes the size of the `map object`. We are not interested on the bytes before this offset. (*Except for some small fragments due to granuality.*)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I finally found the way, derived from a thread [here](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.kernel/browse_thread/thread/dd2bf39d8dfc4927/fbd6270ac77f2ce1?pli=1). The trick is using VirtualUnlock() on the ranges I need to uncommit; although this function returns FALSE with error 0x9e ("The segment is already unlocked"), memory is actually released, even if the pages were modified (file is correctly updated).

Here's my sample test program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

void getenter(void)
{
    int     ch;
    for(;;)
    {
        ch = getch();
        if( ch == '\n' || ch == '\r' ) return;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char*   fname = "c:\\temp\\MMFTest\\TestFile.rar";      // 54 MB
    HANDLE  hfile = CreateFile( fname, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS, NULL );
    if( hfile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "CreateFile() error 0x%08x\n", GetLastError() );
        getenter();
        return 1;
    }

    HANDLE map_handle = CreateFileMapping( hfile, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE | SEC_RESERVE, 0, 0, 0);
    if( map_handle == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "CreateFileMapping() error 0x%08x\n", GetLastError() );
        getenter();
        CloseHandle(hfile);
        return 1;
    }

    char* map_ptr = (char*) MapViewOfFile( map_handle, FILE_MAP_WRITE | FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0 );
    if( map_ptr == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "MapViewOfFile() error 0x%08x\n", GetLastError() );
        getenter();
        CloseHandle(map_handle);
        CloseHandle(hfile);
        return 1;
    }

    // Memory usage here is 704KB
    printf("Mapped.\n"); getenter();

    for( int n = 0 ; n < 10000 ; n++ )
    {
        map_ptr[n*4096]++;
    }

    // Memory usage here is ~40MB
    printf("Used.\n"); getenter();

    if( !VirtualUnlock( map_ptr, 5000 * 4096 ) )
    {
        // Memory usage here is ~20MB
        // 20MB already freed!
        fprintf( stderr, "VirtualUnlock() error 0x%08x\n", GetLastError() );
        getenter();
        UnmapViewOfFile(map_ptr);
        CloseHandle(map_handle);
        CloseHandle(hfile);
        return 1;
    }

    // Code never reached
    printf("VirtualUnlock() executed.\n"); getenter();

    UnmapViewOfFile(map_ptr);
    CloseHandle(map_handle);
    CloseHandle(hfile);

    printf("Unmapped and closed.\n"); getenter();

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the working set of the program is reduced after executing VirtualUnlock(), just as I needed. I only need to keep track of the pages I change in order to unlock as appropriate.

Comment: Great, thanks for sharing this. I was looking desperately for a way how to control amount of memory used by memory mapped files, and I was already losing hope it can be done.

I only hope MS will not disable this is some future OS.

After all, why cannot we simply commit and decommit the pages as desired?

Comment: Note: the error code you describe seems to be expected based on VirtualUnlock doc remark:

"If any of the pages in the specified range are not locked, VirtualUnlock removes such pages from the working set, sets last error to ERROR_NOT_LOCKED, and returns FALSE."

Comment: One more note: the experiment is somewhat misleading. The working set of the process is reduced, but that does not necessarily mean the page is discarded. If you will map if again, you can see you get it immediately, without any page file activity. See my experiment in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525202/how-can-i-decommit-a-file-mapped-page/3525266#3525266

Answer (score 4):

Just map the whole file to memory. This consumes virtual but not physical memory. The file is read from disk piecewise and is evicted from memory by the same policies that govern the swap file.

Comment: Well, that's precisely the problem. The policies that govern the swap file tend to keep the contents in memory much more than those of the file cache, so accessing the mapped file will eventually swap out most of the other processes.

Answer (score 2):

VirtualUnlock does not appear to work. What you need to do is call 
FlushViewOfFile(map_ptr,0) immediately before UnmapViewOfFile(map_ptr).
Windows Task Manager will not show the physical memory usage. Use ProcessExplorer from SysInternals

Answer (score 1):

Are you mapping the whole file as one block with MapViewOfFile? If you are, try mapping smaller parts. You can flush a view with FlushViewOfFile()

Comment: I don't access the file sequentially; there's a random pattern I cannot control for accessing the file, so mapping small parts of it will be very innefective. Besides, FlushViewOfFile() doesn't free any memory; only forces the writing of the dirty pages.