# Minimize memory usage with Boost's file_mapping and mapped_region?

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost, file-io

For this problem I am loading a large three-dimensional volume from file into a program, but only need to look at three planes (x,y,z) at a time usually. I am currently using Boost::Interprocess::File_Mapping to create a map of the file (32 GB) and loading it onto my system which has 24 GB of RAM. The current method uses a single Boost::Interprocess::Mapped_Region for the file. The memory usage quickly approaches 99%.

I am new to the world of memory mapped file i/o and want to know how best to segment the file to reduce the amount of memory usage. Would creating reduced sized regions (each Z plane for instance) improve the results? I would like to use as little memory as possible without causing adverse effects.

Am I going about this the correct way, or is there a more straightforward method for performing this?

Comment: You've forgot to specify the platform.

Comment: I didn't specify the platform because the concept is designed to be independent. I am debugging on Windows however which I should have included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, it normally works OK. I've created a test application (sorry I hate boost because I think its quality is appaling, my sample uses ATL instead, but underlying Windows API are the same):

```
HRESULT TestMain( LPCTSTR strFileName )
{
    CAtlFile file;
    HRESULT hr = file.Create( strFileName, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, OPEN_EXISTING );
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        return hr;
    CAtlFileMapping<BYTE> mapping;
    hr = mapping.MapFile( file );
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        return hr;
    size_t sz = mapping.GetMappingSize();
    BYTE res = 0;
    for( size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++ )
        res ^= mapping[ i ];

    printf( "Read the complete file, %Iu bytes, the XOR is %.2X\n", sz, int( res ) );
    return S_OK;
}
```

When asked to read a 12GB file on my machine with 8GB RAM, I saw the effect you're describing (resource monitor memory data for my process: commit 25 MB, private 20 MB, working set and shareable 6.5 GB which is amount of my free RAM). However, multiple sources on the Internets say those numbers mean nothing and don't affect performance, because unused physical pages will be discarded as soon as any process requests more memory, and this process is very cheap (unless of course you're writing to your memory mapped file).

Or, if you're really unhappy about this behavior, you can free unused portions yourself, by calling VirtualUnlock, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1882478/126995

Or, you can only map the portions of the file you need.

But the best you can do about it - optimize the layout of your data. If in your data file you're keeping voxels as `double voxels[x][y][z]`, store them as `struct { double voxels[8][8][8] } blocks[x/8][y/8][z/8]` instead. This way, the block size is exactly 4kb which is a page size, and if you only need to access e.g. XZ plane, you'll save **a lot** of I/O bandwidth, by orders of magnitude. Just don't mess up with misalignment, i.e. if you have a header before your data, make sure the size of the header is 4kb*n where n is integer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I knew the layout could improve things, but didn't know if my results were what was supposed to happen. I may try using the native memory mapping as I also hate using Boost.